# NumPy Array grouping?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am new to using NumPy and trying to work with arrays, tried building a 1D,2D and now a 3D array. But I wasn't sure why ndim thinks that this is a 2D array even though it has 3 rows

```
In [26]: c= array ([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])

In [27]: c
Out[27]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [28]: c.ndim
Out[28]: 2
```

This one shows up as a 3D array. How does the grouping work in a 3D array?

```
In [30]: d= array([[[1], [2]], [[3], [4]]])

In [31]: d
Out[31]: 
array([[[1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4]]])

In [32]: d.ndim
Out[32]: 3
```

Comment: 3 rows doesn't mean 3 dimensions.

Comment: Then what does dimension mean for an array?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the nested list you're passing to the `array` constructor. What kind of expression would you use to retrieve an element?

```
A[i][j]    # This?
A[i][j][k] # Or this?
```

If it's the first option, you have a 2D array. If it's the second option, you have a 3D array. The number of indexes you need is the dimension of the array. It has nothing to do with how many rows or columns are in it.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions are different than items.  In your situation, you can check if you have a 2d array by asking for the length,

```
len(c)
```

would give you 3, since you have 3 elements at the top index c.  If you want to check how many elements are in each of those top three, you would do

```
len(c[0])
len(c[1])
len(c[2])
```

which would all give you 3.  Then you can do c[0][0]. However, if you try to do

```
len(c[0][0][0])
```

you will get an error since the index c[0][0][0] is not a list or array, so it can not be indexed.

Your second example of a 3 dimensions can be indexed d[0][0][0] since

```
(*FIRST*[*SECOND*[*THIRD*[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]])
```

where FIRST is d, second is d[0], and third is d[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions depend on the number of groupings, not the number of rows. The first example is an array of arrays, so it's 2D. The second is an array of arrays of arrays (with 1 number in them) so it's 3D.

Answer (score 0):

You're not talking about dimension. I think you're looking for shape:

```
In [8]: c.shape
Out[8]: (3, 4)
```

Which gives you rows and columns.

```
In [9]: c.ndim
Out[9]: 2
```

Gives number of dimensions you can index/subscript by. If you have a small raster of pixels as 2D, 3D would be a volume of voxels.